# class and struct nesting

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am not very clear about this code

outer is a `class` and the inner a `struct`, can anyone help me explain it?

```
class Stack {
    struct Link {
        void* data;
        Link* next;
        Link(void* dat, Link* nxt):
        data(dat),next(nxt) {}
    }* head;
public:
    Stack():head(0) {}
    ~Stack() {
        require(head==0,"Stack not empty");
    }
    void push(void* dat) {
        head = new Link( dat, head );
    }
    void peek() const {
        return head ? head->data : 0;
    }

    void* pop() {
        if(head == 0)  return 0;
        void* result = head->data;
        Link* oldHead = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete oldHead;
        return result;
    }
};
```

my question is focus on the first few lines

```
class Stack {
    struct Link {
        void* data;
        Link* next;
        Link(void* dat, Link* nxt):
        data(dat),next(nxt) {}
    }* head;
```

what the relation between `class Stack` and `struct Link`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Link` is declared inside `Stack`, and since it's `private` by default, it can't be used outside the class.

Also, `Stack` has a member `head` which is of type `Link*`.

The only difference between `class` and `struct` is the default access level - `public` for struct and `private` for class, so don't let "struct declared inside a class" confuse you. Other than the access level, it's the same as "class declared inside a class" or "struct declared inside a struct".

Comment: The difference between `class` & `struct` also matters in case of Inheritance.Inheritance is `private`by default in case of classes while it is `public` in case of structures.

Comment: @Als isn't that a side-effect of the access level inside the class?

Comment: *[Side-Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))*? Why? How?

Comment: what element is in the Stack?

Comment: @user1279988 `head`. It's declared right after the `struct` definition.

Comment: @Als all my lurking around on SO have led me to believe that that's the only difference (other than `class` can also be used as a keyword for template declaration).

Answer (score 5):

Class `Stack` and struct `Link` are **[nested](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr061.htm)**.
Note that nested classes have certain limitations regarding accessing of elements of nested and the enclosing class.

Since, `Link` is declared under `private` access specifier in class `Struct` it cannot be accessed outside the class `Struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Struct `Link` is inner-declared in the class (the correct term is nested). It can be accessed only in the class (due to its default private accessor level). The struct could have been referred with `Stack::Link` if it was declared public.

The reason for such declaration in this case is that only the inner methods of the class need to use the links and `struct` is providing better code organization. However as long as no other class needs to access the `struct` such declaration provides better encapsulation.